# ionic 2 dynamic Variables in ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to make dynamic ngmodel , but give me error this code. How can ı make dynamic ngModel?

```
veritext={};
```

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let ver of grafik" >  
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="veritext.ver.value" class="verigondertext" >
</ion-item>
```

Comment: _give me error this code_.. what error is it?

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code you can try editing it like this.

instead of declaring `{}` object make it `[]` array . since you are looping the `grafik`

```
grafik=[];
```

lets assume you have this array

```
grafik = [
{ 
veritext: {   ver:'',  val:''  }
},
{ 
veritext: {   ver:'',  val:''  }
}  
]
```

on your html

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of grafik" >  
     <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.veritext.val">
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ahmet

Please use following code

```
veritext={};
<ion-item *ngFor="let ver of grafik" >  
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="ver.value" class="verigondertext" >
</ion-item>
```

Make sure if **'value'** key is not able in grafik array then you get error.

I hope it's work fo you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will solve your problem :)

```
   [(ngModel)]="veritext[ver.value]"
```